# Append Dataframes of different dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple dataframes with a different number of rows and columns respectively.

example:

df1:

```
a   b   c   d

0   1   5   6
8   9   8   7
```

and df2:

```
g   h

9   8
4   5
6   7
```

I have to append both the dataframes without a change in their dimensions.

The desired output should be one dataframe Result_df as:

```
a   b   c   d

0   1   5   6
8   9   8   7


g   h

9   8
4   5
6   7
```

Can anyone please help me to append dataframes without change in their structure.

Thank you

Comment: that means columns will just be a,b,c,d with g directly underneath a, h underneath b, and the rest nans? there will be no g or h column after the merge

Comment: yes, this is more like it, as I showed in my desired result.

Comment: and possibly i want to add a blank line as well while appending the dataframes.

Comment: ok. kindly share what u have tried, so we know where to kick off from

Comment: sure,  `pd.concat([df1,df2])`. But it is not giving the desired output that I want and shared in the question

Comment: basically u want to create a dataframe of the column names and concat, cos u cant concat dataframes with the column name of the other dataframe still persisting. and i mentioned that in my first comment

Comment: yes, I don't want to relate any observation or column name between two dataframes.Just a simple append operation with no structural change. is it possible?

Comment: dont think that is possible. i might be wrong.

Comment: continue with ur first comment, i want g an h column after the merge. Thank you